# Supporting different sizes and densities imageview

Tags: android, xml, screen-density

I have a viewpager with imageviews and I have set it like this:

```
mViewPager.setPageMargin((int) getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.view_pager_margin));

<dimen name="view_pager_margin">-250dp</dimen>
```

Now, I've created the following dimens files:

[image]

But, when I start Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P emulators they both share the dimens.xml(xxhdpi) file and the images don't look good on both. What would be the best approach so my images can look as they are supposed to on every device?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://design.google.com/devices/, the 5X and 6P both have dimensions of 411 dp x 731 dp.  However, the 5X is an xxhdpi device, whereas the 6P is an xxxhdpi device, so they're actually using different dimens.xml files.

I would recommend defining your dimens.xml based on actual screen dimensions rather than screen density.  For example, a dimens-w400dp.xml would apply to both devices.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: Yes, one is an xxhdpi device and the other is xxxhdpi, but for some reason in my project, they both get the dimens from the xxhdpi file. I've created a dimens-w400dp.xml file but I get the same problem, the spacing between the images on both devices are different.

Comment: `setPagerMargin(int)` is expecting a pixel size.  Maybe try `resources.getDimensionPixelSize`?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I still get the same result. On https://design.google.com/devices/ it says that 6P is xxxhdpi, but on the emulator it says 6P is xxhdpi.